# Apache SAMOA analysis topology

Tags: weka, apache-storm, moa, samoa

Are there any examples, tutorials, blogs, books, videos, anything that can show me how can I create a topology using Apache SAMOA?

I'm concretely interested in using SAMOA for Storm and I would like to build a topology in which one part of topology does some clustering (or association rules), but I'm not able to find not even a single example to do that. Can anyone explain how to do that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work on SAMOA with STORM, you should install and configure STORM firstly.
STORM topology has several worker nodes which are nimbus, zookeeper, supervisor. These workers may reside in different machines, so, for the beginning, I suggest you to use **[wirbelsturm](https://github.com/miguno/wirbelsturm)** which helps you to set up virtual machines for topology with ease.

My installation steps were;

```
- Vagrant 1.7.2+
- Virtualbox 4.3.x
- Parallel
- Storm 0.9.3 (release and code-base)
- Wirbelsturm

!! Versions were very important for me because I could not succeed with latest ones.
```

On SAMOA you should compile and package STORM,

```
# Build Storm
$ cd storm
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests=true

# Build the storm-starter example
$ cd examples/storm-starter
$ mvn compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology
$ mvn package
```

Finally, do not forget to change configuration files;

```
- Vagrantfile
- wirbelsturm.yaml
- hosts
```

When running on SAMOA;

```
$ bin/samoa storm target/SAMOA-Storm-0.4.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar "PrequentialEvaluation -d /tmp/dump.csv -i 1000000 -f 100000 -l (org.apache.samoa.learners.classifiers.trees.VerticalHoeffdingTree -p 4) -s (org.apache.samoa.moa.streams.generators.RandomTreeGenerator -c 2 -o 10 -u 10)"
```

If your installation & configuration is right, you should see your topology on Storm UI: http://localhost:28080/

For more and detailed infromation;

- [Executing-SAMOA-with-Apache-Storm](https://samoa.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Executing-SAMOA-with-Apache-Storm.html)
- [running-multi-node-storm-cluster](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/#installing-storm)
- [wirbelsturm#how-it-works](https://github.com/miguno/wirbelsturm#how-it-works)
- [wirbelsturm-one-click-deploy-storm-kafka-clusters-with-vagrant-puppet](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/03/17/wirbelsturm-one-click-deploy-storm-kafka-clusters-with-vagrant-puppet/)

I hope this helps.